# Delete all data stored in a Class Construct SWIFT3

Tags: ios, swift, class, object, swift3

Fairly new to swift and object orientated altogether so please bear with me. I have a small class that I used to store data.

```
class Coin {

    //MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    var symbol: String
    var date: Date
    var time: String


    init?(name: String, symbol: String, date: Date, time: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.date = date
        self.time = time



        if name.isEmpty  {
            return nil
        }

    }


}
```

Through the course of the application, this data needs to be updated to display up to date information. Whenever I attempt to load data from these the COIN object, I end up with double the data in the array I am loading it into.
Eg, first run will be 10 objects, second will be 20.

This is how the data is being loaded from the object in a seperate class

```
var coins = [Coin]()

    private func loadCoins(CoinName: String, Symbol: String, Date: Date, Time: String) {
        guard let coin1 = Coin(name: CoinName, symbol: Symbol, date: Date, time:Time) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate coin1")
        }



        coins += [coin1]

    }
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this duplication of data?

Comment: When trying to update, which field values may change or all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the function You use "+= [coin1]" for summing the data. If You want to have array of coin object just use coins.append(coin).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to have a certain number of `Coin` in `coins` at all times, consider mutating your existing coins instead of adding new ones. For example:

```
private func updateCoin(at index: Int, name: String, symbol: String, date: Date, time: String) {
    guard name.isEmpty == false else {
        print("Did not update coin at index \(index) because name was an empty string")
    }
    coins[index].name = name
    coins[index].symbol = symbol
    coins[index].date = date
    coins[index].time = time
}
```

If you will *not* be modifying existing coins, consider making `Coin` a struct and declaring all of its properties as constants. In this case, you would need another method of updating coins. For example, this would work with immutable coins:

```
private func updateCoin(at index: Int, name: String, symbol: String, date: Date, time: String) {
    guard let newCoin = Coin(name: name, symbol: symbol, date: date, time: time) else {
        print("Coin could not be initialized with values name: \(name), symbol: \(symbol), date: \(date), time: \(time)")
    }
    coins[index] = newCoin
}
```